# Transition not working in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, transition

I'm developing my own website, and one of the 'features' it has is that when I go with my mouse over the header, it slides down.

This works well and good on all major browsers. However, with IE 10, it doesn't. Here's the page source:

```
<?php
    echo "<html>
    <head>
        <title>memodesigns</title>
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='style/stylesheet.css'>
    </head>

    <body>";
                include_once('modules/header.php');
            echo "
    </body>

    </html>";
?>
```

This is the header file which is included:

```
<?php

    echo "<div id = 'menucontainer'>
            <div id = 'menu'>
                <p>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a class = 'menu' href = ''>HOME</a></li>
                        <li><a class = 'menu' href = 'about.php'>ABOUT</a></li>
                        <li><a class = 'menu' href = 'portfolio.php'>PORTFOLIO</a></li>
                        <li><a class = 'menu' href = 'rates.php'>RATES</a></li>
                        <li><a class = 'menu' href = 'contact.php'>CONTACT</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>";

?>
```

And the CSS styles being used here:

```
a.menu{
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}

/*menucontainer*/
#menucontainer{
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -8px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-transition: margin-top 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: margin-top 0.5s;
    -o-transition: margin-top 0.5s;
    transition: margin-top 0.5s;
}

/*menucontainer*/
#menucontainer:hover{
    margin-top: 0px;
}

/*menu*/
#menu{
    padding-top: 5px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 12px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 12px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 12px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 12px;
    max-width: 75%;
    height: 25px;
    background-color: #202020;
    font-family: Roboto;
    color: #f3f4f4;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

Would appreciate any help as to why transitions are not working in IE, but working on other major browsers.

Comment: Welcome to Internet Explorer. You won't enjoy your stay.

Comment: I suggest not linking to an uknown site like you did.  Try jsbin or jsfiddle or something similar.

Comment: @DMoses The page is clean. Also, on another note, I've confirmed this in IE 10 on Windows 7 using BrowserStack.

Comment: Any particular reason? Those two sites seem oriented towards HTML and Javascript, rather than PHP.

EDIT: Thanks Ian Carroll

Comment: @MemoNick He was talking about it possibly having viruses, however [VirusTotal has checked your page.](https://www.virustotal.com/en/url/a8ef3de5710fe1e728fc05774545c46010cfda0111d0a9aafae305e9ca51f297/analysis/1373405180/)

Comment: You just won't get as many people clicking on an unknown domain from here.  Ian went through a step most of us are too lazy to do :)

Comment: Here you go... for some reason, this one works in IE: http://jsfiddle.net/b6e4Y/1/

Maybe it's because I'm 'including' it from an external php?

Comment: I tossed your code in a jsfiddle and it worked fine.  Your site that you linked does not.  Diff and see what is different:  http://jsfiddle.net/SE3nw/  (the fiddle doesn't put the text correctly, but it does transition fine)

Comment: Even using something ultra-bare doesn't work :/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I suspect the issue might be compatibility mode.

If you do not have a proper doctype declaration as the very first line in a document, IE will enter compatibility mode and most features will not work as expected. Ensure that you have a valid doctype (`<!DOCTYPE html>` will be fine) and add `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />` to your document `<head>`.

Also, make sure there is no extra whitespace before the doctype that could be introduced by the way you are echoing text in PHP.

Comment: Dang it, I was writing that! D:

Comment: Yeah, IE10 should support the standard property. I think the issue might be compatibility mode.

Answer (score 1):

The given example has no doctype at all. Without valid doctype, **any** version of IE effectively turns into IE5.5.

Also, forget about PHP when you debug any HTML/CSS/Javascript problem. Browsers don't care what your markup is generated with, they see only the resulting HTML code that you can see by clicking 'View source' menu.

Comment: Figured that much (re: PHP). To tell you the truth, I totally <b>forgot</b> about the Doctype. Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `-ms-` vendor prefixes? I'm not entirely sure if this will fix it, but it's worth a shot :)

Seeing your comment, I think JSFiddle is adding something to the page, like normalize.css.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a js solution like jquery?
Something like this might work:

```
$("#menu").mouseenter(
    function(){ 
        $(this).stop().animate({paddingTop:'20px'},'slow')
    });
$("#menu").mouseleave(
    function(e) {
        $(this).stop().animate({paddingTop:'5px'},'slow')
    });
```

Here is the fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/Bobyo/aXgAV/

Comment: Is this solution easier/more feasible? I liked the CSS solution, and it did the job. I know transitions don't work on IE 9 and below, but quite frankly, I don't really care about IE.

Comment: If you don't care about IE9 and below it's better to use css. I peresonaly like to have my animations by js but css is a nice and clean solution if you dopn't care about xbrowser compatibility