# Transition and shadow not working in IE11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have this right side menu which expands when you hover over it. I don't know why but transitions and shadows are not displayed on IE11 even though I have included attributes like -ms-transition.

As far as I'm aware IE supports transitions since IE10, so I can't find a reason for it to not work.

The shadows are also not visible but Chrome and Firefox are fine...

I've spent a lot of time trying to get to the bottom of it, looked at numerous threads with no success.

```js
angular.module('app',[])

.controller('mainCtrl', function() {
  var vm = this;
  
  vm.expanded = false;

  vm.expandCollapseMenu = function() {
    vm.expanded = !vm.expanded;
  };
})
```

```css
.right-side-menu {
 height: 90%;
 width: 20%;
 left: calc(100% - 60px);
 display: flex;
 background: red;
 position: fixed;
 overflow: hidden;
 -webkit-box-shadow:  -1px 0 10px -2px #0000009e;
 -moz-box-shadow:  -1px 0 10px -2px #0000009e;
 box-shadow:  -1px 0 10px -2px #0000009e;
 -webkit-transition: 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.21, 0.69, 0.7, 1);
 -moz-transition: 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.21, 0.69, 0.7, 1);
 -ms-transition: 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.21, 0.69, 0.7, 1);
 -o-transition: 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.21, 0.69, 0.7, 1);
 transition: 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.21, 0.69, 0.7, 1);
}

.right-side-menu.right-side-menu-expanded   {
 left: 80%;
 -webkit-transition: 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.21, 0.69, 0.7, 1);
 -moz-transition: 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.21, 0.69, 0.7, 1);
 -ms-transition: 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.21, 0.69, 0.7, 1);
 -o-transition: 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.21, 0.69, 0.7, 1);
 transition: 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.21, 0.69, 0.7, 1);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
 <head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
    <div ng-controller="mainCtrl as vm">
      <div class="right-side-menu" ng-mouseenter="vm.expandCollapseMenu()"
           ng-mouseleave="vm.expandCollapseMenu()"
           ng-class="{'right-side-menu-expanded': vm.expanded}">
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: try including `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">` this meta tag in html

Comment: There is an issue about not working transitions in IE. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17558426/transition-not-working-in-ie. In your HTML the <!DOCKTYPE html> tag is also missing. This might help you.

Comment: Included both. The result is the same. Check out the latest snippet.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to change the color little bit than you can see the shadow will work.

Code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
 <head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
angular.module('app',[])

.controller('mainCtrl', function() {
  var vm = this;
  
  vm.expanded = false;

  vm.expandCollapseMenu = function() {
    vm.expanded = !vm.expanded;
  };
})
</script>
<style>
.right-side-menu {
 height: 90%;
 width: 20%;
 left: calc(100% - 60px);
 display: flex;
 background: red;
 position: fixed;
 overflow: hidden;
 -webkit-box-shadow:  -1px 0 10px -2px #0000009e;
 -moz-box-shadow:  -1px 0 10px -2px #0000009e;
 /*box-shadow:  -1px 0 10px -2px #0000009e;*/
 box-shadow: -5px -5px 10px -2px #888888;
 -webkit-transition: 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.21, 0.69, 0.7, 1);
 -moz-transition: 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.21, 0.69, 0.7, 1);
 -ms-transition: 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.21, 0.69, 0.7, 1);
 -o-transition: 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.21, 0.69, 0.7, 1);
 transition: 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.21, 0.69, 0.7, 1);
}

.right-side-menu.right-side-menu-expanded   {
 left: 80%;
 -webkit-transition: 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.21, 0.69, 0.7, 1);
 -moz-transition: 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.21, 0.69, 0.7, 1);
 -ms-transition: 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.21, 0.69, 0.7, 1);
 -o-transition: 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.21, 0.69, 0.7, 1);
 transition: 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.21, 0.69, 0.7, 1);
}
</style>
 </head>
 <body>
    <div ng-controller="mainCtrl as vm">
      <div class="right-side-menu" ng-mouseenter="vm.expandCollapseMenu()"
           ng-mouseleave="vm.expandCollapseMenu()"
           ng-class="{'right-side-menu-expanded': vm.expanded}">
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Output in IE 11:

[image]

In IE 11, The output of transition is affected by the lines of css code like the **position** and **calc**.

As you can see in this W3c example that transition is working fine with IE 11.

[Transition Example](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_func_cubic-bezier)

So you can try to have a look and try to modify it.